# Finding all possible distinct palindromes of a string

Tags: java, strings, palindrome

There was some online test where I was asked about finding all possible distinct palindromes of a string.

Here I had to give the count of all possible distinct palindromes of a given string (continuous substring). Here, a single character word is considered a palindrome.

Below is what I did. Can you please tell me if it is good OR there is a scope of improvement?

```
public class Solution {
/*
* Complete the function below.
*/

static int palindrome(String str) {
    String[] strArray = str.split("");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strArray);
    list = list.subList(1, list.size());
    //Set does'nt allow duplicates.
    //Sublist is required because split method gives an extra space.
    Set<String> palindromeSet = new HashSet<>(list);
    String palindromeStr = null;
    for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){
        palindromeStr = list.get(i);
        for(int j = i+1;j<list.size();j++){
            palindromeStr = palindromeStr+list.get(j);
            if(isPalindrome(palindromeStr)){
                palindromeSet.add(palindromeStr);
            }
        }
    }
    return palindromeSet.size();
}

static boolean isPalindrome(String str){
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    for(int i =0;i<(chars.length/2);i++){
        if(chars[i] != chars[chars.length-1-i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    System.out.println(palindrome("arewenotdrawnonwardtonewera"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/*
* Complete the function below.
*/
```

Do you still need it?

```
String[] strArray = str.split("");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strArray);
list = list.subList(1, list.size());
```

That's ugly. You could work with the original `String` or use `str.toCharArray()` if you really needed an array. But you don't.

```
//Set does'nt allow duplicates.
```

True, but rather well-known. And a typo.

```
//Sublist is required because split method gives an extra space.
```

True, but misplaced by a few lines. Full line comments belong before the block they describe.

```
String palindromeStr = null;
for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){
    palindromeStr = list.get(i);
```

This should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    String palindromeStr = list.get(i);
```

Note the spacing.

```
    for(int j = i+1;j<list.size();j++){
        palindromeStr = palindromeStr+list.get(j);
```

This is a pretty slow way of creating what

```
   String palindromeStr = str.substring(i, j);
```

could give you. By creating your string incrementally you gain nothing: Because of strings being immutable, their whole content gets copied on every step.

This way the complexity is `O(n**3)` and could be reduced(*) to `O(n**2)` by simply defining a method working on a substring like

```
 static boolean isPalindrome(String str, int start, int end) ...
```

---

You should improve both spacing (just press Ctrl-Shift-F in Eclipse) and naming, maybe as follows:

- `str` `->` `input`
- `strArray` `->` nothing, just inline it
- `palindromeSet` `->` `palindromes` as it's clearly a set
- `palindromeStr` `->` `substring` or `candidate` as it's not always a palindrome

Your naming is not really bad, but you concentrate on the type too much and I can imagine to get lost in a bunch of names like `intListSetArray`  and `strDoubleMap` without any clue what's the variable good for.

---

I'd bet there's a faster algorithm, but I haven't figured it out yet.

---

(*) I'm assuming that `isPalindrome` is `O(1)` on the average, which is true for normal strings, but not for e.g. `"aaaa....a"`.

Comment: For a faster algorithm, I hypothesize the following: iterate to each character and find all palindromes with that character as the center character of a palindrome (expanding outwards until a palindrome is not possible).  This works for odd length palindromes.  For even length palindromes you pick the space in between characters as the "middle spot" and do the same thing.  I think this is an \$O(n^2)\$ algorithm.

Comment: @JS1 Sure! You expand a palindrome by checking a single character pair, so you really get them all in quadratic time. +++ I guess, it could be done even faster as the degenerate cases like `"aaaa....a"` contain `O(n**2)` palindromes but only `O(n)` *distinct* ones. Maybe something like Rabin–Karp....